# scikit-learn denoising example in pyhton

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I was just seeing [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_image_denoising.html) example from the `scikit-learn` lib. To know more, I want to know what is actually doing these lines.

1)

```
dico = MiniBatchDictionaryLearning(n_components=100, alpha=1, n_iter=500)
V = dico.fit(data).components_
```

Here, what is fit() function actually doing?

2)

```
data = data.reshape(data.shape[0], -1)
```

Here why we are doing reshape it to 2D matrix. If do so for gray scale image,then what I will do for 3 channel Image(Color Image)?

3)

```
 dico.set_params(transform_algorithm=transform_algorithm, **kwargs)
 code = dico.transform(data)
```

Here, what is the doing transform() ??

Comment: Many of these questions can be answered by investing time reading the sklearn documentation, and a complete answer would mostly involve regurgitating this documentation.  Please show some research effort, and clarify what in the documentation was unclear to you.

Comment: @MatthewDrury thanks for replying me . Actually I am working on centralized sparse representation for Image restoration. I want to implement a project, But in that project the process of finding the sprase code is different with respect to this dictionary learning in scikit-learn. that is why i need to write my own function. For all that i need to know what actually doing these functions.